# How to implement XCM into Mock.rs for tests in Pallet?

Tags: rust, xcm, xcmp

How to implement XCM into Morck.rs for tests in Pallet?

I use XCM in my Lib.rs calls.

I have to implement the following:

```
type XcmSender = XcmRouter;
type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
```

However I get an error, that XcmRouter and RuntimeOrigin do not exist. How to import them? Thanks!